# Does point group symmetry also act within "spin space" for a lattice spin system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, symmetry, quantum-spin

As an example, let's consider a quantum spin system on a 2D square lattice. The lattice point group symmetries include $C_4$ rotation, parities, etc.... And let's take $C_2$ symmetry (2-fold rotation) as an example. Now there seem to be 2 ways to define the $C_2$ transformation on **quantum spin operators** $\vec{S}_i$:

(1) $C_2:\vec{S}_i\rightarrow\vec{S}_{-i}$

(2) $C_2:\vec{S}_i\rightarrow A\vec{S}_{-i}$, where $A\in SO(3)$ is the site-independent 2-fold rotation matrix $A=diag(-1,-1,1)$.

(1) means that $C_2$ acts only in **real space**, while (2) means that $C_2$ acts both in **real space** and **spin space**. In definition (2), spin is viewed as a **pseudovector** or **axial vector**, right ?

**My question is:**

Which definition is more "correct" from the **condensed matter physics viewpoint** ?

On the other hand, I think that this question is just a matter of "definition" (at least at the mathematics level), and how do you understand it ?

In definition (2), the rotation matrix $A$ is global, which means that the **quantum spin** at the **origin site** is also rotated (in spin space) while the **origin site** (in real space) is invariant under $C_2$, in other words, the real space point (at which the single spin locates) is unchanged but the spin is changed (in spin space), is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems like whichever definition you take, the symmetry group is always $\text{space group}\times \mathrm{SO}(3)$. So I guess it does not really matter.

Comment: @Meng Cheng  Thanks. In your statement, have you assumed that the spin Hamiltonian has "full" spin-rotation symmetry (e.g., spin-isotropic Heisenberg model) ? If the Hamiltonian has "full" spin-rotation symmetry, it indeed seems that the 2 definitions are equivalent. However, when the "full" spin-rotation symmetry is absent, like the spin-1/2 Kitaev honeycomb model, if we consider the $C_3$ lattice-rotation as an example, we still can give 2 definitions for $C_3$, but now it seems that these 2 definitions are NOT equivalent anymore.... I'm not sure that my understanding is correct, thank you.

Comment: That is a different question now. You can define your own $C_2$ as the lattice reflection times any on-site operation, as long as it helps you (i.e. a symmetry of the Hamiltonian).

Comment: @Meng Cheng I see, thanks for your excellent comments.